# How to extend field in news letter in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, newsletter

I need to add some check boxes in magento news letter.
in newsletter I need to add 3 check boxes.
Men,women,kids and this will be pre selected.

Without changing the core files....I need to add 1 filed and also...save data in that field.
I need to know that how this can i do by local.
like what should we need and how....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're question is pretty vague but I'll give it a try.

You can change the `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/newsletter/subscribe.phtml` by copying it to your theme directory and adding the required checkboxes.

To actually process the data you would need to overwrite the controller. Inchoo (who else) has [a great article](http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/) about this. From a custom extension it would look something like this

`config.xml`

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <tag>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <[yourmodule]_newsletter before="Mage_Newsletter">[Yourmodule]_Newsletter</[yourmodule]_newsletter>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </tag>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

`SubscriberController.php`

```
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Newsletter').DS.'SubscriberController.php');

class [Yourmodule]_Newsletter_SubscriberController extends Mage_Newsletter_SubscriberController
{
   /**
      * New subscription action
      */
    public function newAction()
    {
        // edit the code from the origional Mage_Newsletter_SubscriberController::newAction
    }
}
```

From there on out what you want to do with the data is up to you, if you want to store it in the Magento newsletter table you will need to include an install script in your extension that modifies the existing table.

For that, again, we have an Inchoo [article about installer scripts](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/).

Comment: inchoo is so confusing....can u give me  link for the how to override controller else inchoo....and thanks for the answer

Comment: The link is directly to the article. You can click on the blueish text